# Can I load jQuery dynamically to a local variable rather than to window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing a widget to implement a "Zopim" like live chat. To modify the DOM of the page my widget will live in I'd like to use jQuery, but I want to do that without polluting the global namespace of the host page.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jQuery.noConflict(true)`

> jQuery.noConflict(true) will remove all jQuery variables form global scope.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 1):

Steps

Check if `window.jQuery` is defined. If it is and matches version you need (`jQuery.fn.jquery`) use that version.

Otherwise Load jQuery and use `noConflict(true)` to assign to another variable and maintain any existing `$` in page

Comment: @KevinB I thought so and had to go into source because I never stopped to figure out that `$` gets assigned to `_$` before jQuery assigns `$` and then noConflict(true) can map it back again

Comment: Ah yes i remember that part of the src, very clever. Basically preserves the previous copy so that you can then revert it back with noConflict. It does the same with window.jQuery if you include the `true` parameter.